# Create a word replacement dictionary from list of tuples

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples wich I am trying to make a word replacement dictionary out of.
My list is similar to this:

```
word_list = [('horse','et'),('horses','ft'),('dog','et'),('dogs','ft')]
```

I have managed to create a dict like this:

```
word_dict = { 'et': ['horse','dog'], 'ft': ['horses','dogs'] }
```

What I would wan't is a dictionary like this:

```
word_dict = { 'horse':'dog', 'horses':'dogs' }
```

I am new to python and been unable to figure this out or find an answer on here.
How can I create this dictionary?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you define the order? 'horses':'dogs' or 'dogs':'horses'

Comment: What do `'et'` and `'ft'` represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
>>> word_dict = {'et': ['horse','dog'], 'ft': ['horses','dogs']}
>>> dict(word_dict.values())
{'horses': 'dogs', 'horse': 'dog'}
```